# ViewState syntax error in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get a strange error message when using viewState on a web page. Using example code from Microsoft generates this error on ViewState["Text"]:

> Error 17  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'method group'

It seems the error is not in the code, but in config or something.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using vaCommonLibrary;

public partial class lista : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public String Text
    {
        get 
        { 
            object o = ViewState["Text"]; 
            return (o == null)? String.Empty : (string)o;
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["Text"] = value;
        }
    }
```

I get another error further down in my code:

```
ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
```

gives

> Error 1   Invalid token '[' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration

Comment: What if you hit F12 when you have your cursor on `ViewState`?

Comment: Your second error sounds like that code isn't in the right place - and it's in code you haven't shown us. If you just close the class after the code you *have* shown us, do you still have that error?

Comment: I get into the obj browser on the row protected virtual StateBag ViewState { get; }

Comment: Please show the full code.

Comment: Hmm, your questions have taken me half the way... Updating this on monday. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

> Your second error sounds like that code isn't in the right place

Absolutely correct. The code was right, but further down in my code there was a { missing after an IF-statement, which caused later parentheses to mismatch leading to "strange" errors. I should have seen that, but I'm kind of new to C#, and just started to migrate all my VB.NET code to C#.

Thanks.